# Passing pointers with space allocated by malloc

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free, parameter-passing

I've just written a function that returns a pointer to a block of memory allocated by malloc.  If I call free() on the returned pointer, will this free the memory?

I tried reading up on this, but I can't find anything that says whether you can call a different pointer pointing to the same location and whether that will free all the memory or not.

This is probably majorly basic, I think I can't find the info because I'm searching for it wrong.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes calling `free` will free the memory.  Its not the pointer that get freed but the memory that the pointer points to that is freed.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm guessing the information on how much memory was allocated is stored elsewhere, so that when 'free' is called, it knows how much to free up?

Comment: @RichardSchneider What if I have a function,I am allocating some memory using malloc and a pointer,actually I am extending an array. Now I have to pass the same array using return.Now I cannot even free that before I return.What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass to `free()` **the value** obtained from `malloc()`.

```
int *x = malloc(42 * sizeof *x);
int *p = &x[0];
free(p);                /* ok, same as free x; x and p have the same value */
```

---

Edit: another example

```
int *x = malloc(42 * sizeof *x);
for (k = 0; k < 24; k++) *x++ = 0; /* zero first 24 elements */
free(x - 24);
```

Comment: +1 *the value* is the key here and what OP doesn't seem to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking here, but if what you're asking is:

```
Can I call free() on a pointer which points to a location within the allocated block?
```

then the answer is "no" -- you must pass `free()` the exact pointer which you got back from `malloc()`. Trying to `free()` an internal pointer, or a pointer to memory which was not allocated by `malloc()`, memory corruption or a crash are likely to occur.

Comment: I think you misunderstood OP's question.